# Modifying width and height of a div element inside an iframe - cross domain policy

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cross-domain, styling

I have a domain and a subdomain. Domain is under my control, the subdomain is pointed to an affiliate whitelabel website, i.e. DNS points to their IP. I want to load the products through iframes on the domain.

I understand that I cannot use JavaScript to change the styling due to the cross domain policy. What I want to accomplish is to modify the height and width of a div deep inside the iframe.

Using a php simple load content is not working, because the page is heavily scripted, and if I am doing that, the framework of the page appears, yet no content is available.

Please point me to a practical solution? I know jquery enough to be able to replace, add styling to things on the same domain, iframe or not iframe. But I have no idea how to do it on the subdomain.
I can control the subdomain, ie I can change the dns back to what I want, but that will stop the whitelabel site from working. I can't add any headers.

Answer (score 0):

The postMessage function should help you here, provided you can put your own JavaScript code on both domains.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Something like this should work:

Parent

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("whatever");
iframe.contentWindow.postMessage("hello");
```

Iframe

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event)
{
    if (event.origin !== "http://your-parent-domain.com") return; // for security

    // do something here with event.data
}
```

Comment: As I said, the subdomain is a whitelabel, a subdomain pointed to the affiliate program IP, so I cannot control the content on it.